# index in a string versus in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Is there anyway to reconcile the two ? Ie when i set the text of a richtextform from a string, a given characters index in the string does not match the position of it in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the WordWrap property is False.

On extremely long lines you're going to run into RightMargin.  It is not infinite, the maximum right margin depends on the font size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be okay, with this my sample text:

> *"Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion; only make statements you can back up with an appropriate reference, or personal experiences"*

Using the code:

```
  richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("back up");
  textBox1.Text.IndexOf("back up");
```

Both have results of: 112

It seems you are using the Rtf property of the RichTextBox that contains extra tags for its formatting?